# seeking alternative of rails helper_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the alternative of rails helper_method? as it is not supported in recent versions. 
I tried putting a helper method in the application.rb controller and in views, tried to use it.

```
app/controllers/application.rb
helper_method :sidebar_values
def sidebar_values
@food_preferences = FoodPreference.all
@food_types = FoodType.all
@cuisines = Cuisine.all
end


app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<% @food_preferences.each do |fp| %>
<p><%= fp.name%></p>
<%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not calling `sidebar_values` (and so your variables are not initialized)

Comment: helper_method is supported in the recent versions. http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe you mean `before_filter`? That would set the variables you are looking for. Unless there is a `sidebar_values` call not shown here...